# PHP Dynamic Select Onchange NOT WORKING

Tags: php, jquery, select, dynamic, joomla

i'm trying to do a dynamic select, i've tried some examples here on stackoverflow but it still not working..

i think the code is simple.. choose the brand of a car and then the filtered models appear ..

i'm using joomla, jquery and php (all of them on their latest version)

```html
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript("/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js");


//CONNECTION ON  BD IS WORKING NORMALLY
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxModeloRequest(val)
{
 $.ajax({
 type: 'post',
 url: 'veiculomodelo.php',
 data: {
  get_marca:val
 },
 success: function (response) {
  document.getElementById("modelo").innerHTML=response; 
 }
 });
}

</script>


  
<span style="font-size: 15px;    font-weight: 500;    line-height: 18px;    margin-bottom: 8px;    text-transform: uppercase;">Marca</span>
<select id="marca" name="marca" class="inputbox" onchange="ajaxModeloRequest">
    <?php

    
    // Get a new JDatabaseQuery object
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    
                    
    
    // construindo query veiculo marca
    $query->select(array('id', 'marca'));
    
    $query->from($db->quoteName('#__veiculo_marca'));
    $query->where($db->quoteName('tipo_fk') .'=' . $db->quote('1'));
    
    // Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
    $db->setQuery($query);
    
    // Returns an indexed array of associated arrays from the table records returned by the query
    $results = $db->loadAssocList();
    
    foreach ($results as $row) :
      echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['marca'] . "</option>";
    endforeach;
    
    
    ?>
</select>

<span style="font-size: 15px;    font-weight: 500;    line-height: 18px;    margin-bottom: 8px;    text-transform: uppercase;">Modelo</span>
<select id="modelo" name="modelo" class="inputbox">

</select>
```

and this is the code that is called .. file veiculomodelo.php

```html
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;


$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript("/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js");



if(isset($_POST['get_marca']))
{

    //conectando com o banco de dados para trazer os carros
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    
    // Get a new JDatabaseQuery object
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);


    $marca = $_POST['get_marca'];

    // construindo query veiculo modelo
    $query->select(array('id', 'modelo'));
    
    $query->from($db->quoteName('#__veiculo_modelo'));
    $query->where($db->quoteName('marca_fk') .'=' . $marca);
    
    // Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
    $db->setQuery($query);
    
    // Returns an indexed array of associated arrays from the table records returned by the query
    $results = $db->loadAssocList();

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($find))
 {
  echo "<option>".$row['city']."</option>";
 }
 exit;

/*    
    foreach ($results as $row) :
      echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['modelo'] . "</option>";
    endforeach;
*/
    //exit;
}
?>
```

and thats it.. can someone tell me why it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1):

[image: There is a javascript issue on the site]Your code for onchange isn't sending the value to the function.

use this

```
<select id="marca" name="marca" class="inputbox" onchange="ajaxModeloRequest(this.value);">
```

On the ajax call use jQuery.ajax Instead of $.ajax

Comment: Can you share the page url or sreenshot of the values that are being sent in post?

Comment: www.autoam.com.br

Comment: the fields are marca (for brand) and modelo (for model)

Comment: I just updated my answer, there is a javascript issue on the site

Comment: use

jQuery.ajax

Instead of $.ajax

Comment: changed.. now the console isn't showing errors, but the problem stills

Comment: Remove defined('_JEXEC') or die; from  veiculomodelo.php

Comment: i've changed the url path because the site wasnt finding the file veiculomodelo.php
changed to  
 '/templates/theme3140/html/mod_search/veiculomodelo.php',
and now i'm having error 500 on the console

Comment: You need to fix that 500 error because script is not returning any data

Comment: Do you need developer for your work? I can share profile of someone good at it at a very nominal hourly rate.

Comment: i've tried to simplify the code returning only an 
 echo "<option value='6'>CORSA</option>"; and it worked,
i think when i remove the  defined('_JEXEC'), i cant use the Jfactory class, causing the error 500..  i dont have money to pay a developer

Comment: its a easy thing to do. And no, its not due to JEXEC statement.. You can not use JFactory out of Joomla, you will need to build a small component and place that veiulomodelo.php code in that component and hit that pass that component's browser absolute url in the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative for others finding this thread, you can use RSForms Pro which has a built-in interface for conditional fields and allows code to pull from database tables:

https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/custom-scripting/auto-populate-a-list-from-a-table.html

For multiple filters, you can either change your submit button to say NEXT and set the Return URL to the same page but with the chosen values (ie site.com/myform?model={model:value}

Or you change set an onchange in javascript to reload the window with the variables.

Then do a $_GET for those and include them in the database query for subsequent dropdowns if set.

I like this way because it is integrated with Joomla better for email functionality, menu items and modules, and has a lot of other functionality.